# Preventing a program from breaking my Bash script

Tags: bash, s3cmd

I'm using S3cmd in a bash script upon startup. If it returns an error code, the script is ready to do something. However, s3cmd seem to (sometimes) break it all when an error occurs, and outputs information on screen. It just exists my script.

How do I prevent a program from breaking my Bash script? If something is wrong, I just want the bash script to keep on doing the next thing in line.

EDIT: It seems this only happens with **/etc/rc.local**. If I runt the script as something else (/home/whateverscript) it does as I want it to.

Comment: By "breaking" you mean the script stops running?

Comment: Then you probably have relative paths messing up your execution. Also, as you said the script is run upon startup, you may have unset variables on which your code rely.

Comment: Yes, @VaughnCato, but it only seems to be the case when it's run as rc.local.

Comment: did you check the permissions ?

Comment: If you can show us how you are using the S3cmd inside you bash script, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @JtheRocker s3cmd sync --recursive --delete-removed --config="$HEMMAPPEN/.s3cfg" "$SOURCEFOLDER" "$TARGETFOLDER/"

Answer (score 0):

May be you can wrap your

```
s3cmd sync --recursive --delete-removed --config="$HEMMAPPEN/.s3cfg" "$SOURCEFOLDER" "$TARGETFOLDER/"
```

in the script as below,

`outputText=$(s3cmd sync --recursive --delete-removed --config="$HEMMAPPEN/.s3cfg" "$SOURCEFOLDER" "$TARGETFOLDER/" 2>&1;echo ,$?)`

This will redirect your stderr to stdout (`2>&1`) and the variable *outputText* would contain your desired output (in the form *stdout,exit_status*) of the command, if it's required later in the script context.

If you don't want stdout but only the status of the command in *outputText*, you can use the following

`status=$(s3cmd sync --recursive --delete-removed --config="$HEMMAPPEN/.s3cfg" "$SOURCEFOLDER" "$TARGETFOLDER/" > /dev/null 2>&1;echo $?)`

*status* variable would contain the status of teh command that was run.

I hope it makes sense. Please comment, if it hasn't solved your problem.